# Horizontal scrolling is too sensitive on notification drawer menu in SE Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

When scrolling the notification bar, with the slightest movement to the right the list will be hidden.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Also happens to drawer menu on the left, but it also happens on most drawer menus (including Google apps).